# In WEKA, can I roundup a range after discretization?

Tags: attributes, weka

I have a numeric type attribute, and I discretized it into 6 bins.
But, after discretization, the range looks like `(3.663336-4.325577]`

If I want it to be roundup or looked like `(3.7-4.3]` what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to round to one decimal place through Weka. However, the [MathExpression](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html) filter provides `ceil` and `floor` operations, as well as multiplication and division. This means that before discretization you could run a series of MathExpression filters to get the values you're after. See [this page](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Using+the+MathExpression+filter) for some example usage.